# vim/vimscript - how to identify help window or the 'Help' filetype in script?

Tags: vim

How can I identify the help window or the 'Help' filetype in a script?

Examples:

This can be done with preview windows

```
if &previewwindow
  echo "preview window identified"
  " do more stuff
endif
```

I can interactively check for the help filetype:

```
:set filetype?
```

But how can I do one/either of these in a vimscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&optionname` to get the value of the option and just do a string compare on the result to check for the help filetype

```
if &filetype == 'help'
    " stuff for help window
endif
```

Comment: +1, but I think it would be better to write the first line in this way: "You can use &optionname to get the value of the option".